# Are the determinants of two specific matrices equal?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose F is a field, $X \in M_n(F)$, $XX^t = I$, $det(X) = 1$, $X = \begin{bmatrix} A & B \\ C & D \end{bmatrix}$, where A and D are square matrices.

Is it always true that det(A) = det(D)?

This statement seems to be true for all the examples I have tried, but I do not know how to prove it in general.

Any help will be appreciated.